# How to use deconvolution with MNIST database

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deconvolution, conv-neural-network

I am a newbie in CNN and I am trying the code the Deconvolution (to generate feature maps) in MNIST database (because it's the simplest one to learn for a beginner). I want my model to generate feature maps at the end.The idea is to implement the paper [Saliency Detection Via Dense Convolution Network](https://www.intelcomp-design.com/Archives/ISCSAI%20ISSUE3/ISCSAI013.pdf) to some extent.

Here is the complete code that I am trying to run:

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
import keras.backend as K
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten, Dropout, Activation, Reshape
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, UpSampling2D
from keras.initializers import RandomNormal

init = RandomNormal(mean = 0., stddev = 0.02)

def GeneratorDeconv(image_size = 28): 

    L = int(image_size)

    inputs = Input(shape = (100, ))
    x = Dense(512*int(L/16)**2)(inputs) #shape(512*(L/16)**2,)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Reshape((int(L/16), int(L/16), 512))(x) # shape(L/16, L/16, 512)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(256, (4, 4), strides = (2, 2),
                        kernel_initializer = init,
                        padding = 'same')(x) # shape(L/8, L/8, 256)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(128, (4, 4), strides = (2, 2),
                        kernel_initializer = init,
                        padding = 'same')(x) # shape(L/4, L/4, 128)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(64, (4, 4), strides = (2, 2),
                        kernel_initializer = init,
                        padding = 'same')(x) # shape(L/2, L/2, 64)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(3, (4, 4), strides= (2, 2),
                        kernel_initializer = init,
                        padding = 'same')(x) # shape(L, L, 3)
    images = Activation('tanh')(x)

    model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = images)
    model.summary()
    return model

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 1

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)


model = GeneratorDeconv()

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

The function *def GeneratorDeconv(image_size = 28):* I picked from [ProgramCreek Python](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/93303/keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2DTranspose)

Now, I am confused that how can I embed it into my own custom model. Up to *model.compile(...)* the program runs okay. But at *model.fit(...)* , it gives error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_2 to have 2
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 28, 28, 1)

I don't know how to resolve the issues. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input to your model is:

```
    inputs = Input(shape = (100, ))
```

This will take a vector in the shape of (samples, 100), so it expects a 2D input.

However:

```
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
>>>x_train shape: (60000, 28, 28, 1)
```

You are inputting a 4D array, when you specified that your input took a 2D one. That is what is causing the error.

I made some edits to your architecture so the shapes match up and it actually trains:

```
def GeneratorDeconv(image_size = 28):

    L = int(image_size)

    inputs = Input(shape = (28, 28,1))
    x = Dense(512*int(L/16)**2)(inputs)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(256, (4, 4), strides = (2, 2),
                    kernel_initializer = init,
                    padding = 'same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(128, (4, 4), strides = (2, 2),
                    kernel_initializer = init,
                    padding = 'same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(64, (4, 4), strides = (2, 2),
                    kernel_initializer = init,
                    padding = 'same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(3, (4, 4), strides= (2, 2),
                    kernel_initializer = init,
                    padding = 'same')(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(10)(x)
    images = Activation('tanh')(x)

    model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = images)
    model.summary()
    return model
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try the code. I have one more confusion. How can I visualise ( by cv2.imshow or something) the feature maps as images?

Comment: I'm sorry, that I'm not sure of, and it is a separate question altogether. Get back to me on whether the code works well for you though!

Comment: The code is working fine now. Thank you. Now please tell me how can i visualize feature maps as images from the model above?

Comment: If the code works please mark the answer as accepted. I am sorry I do not know how to visualize feature maps as images. There is a good resource here though: https://blog.keras.io/how-convolutional-neural-networks-see-the-world.html